# regex for replacing with tab

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am having a large data base around 80k data.
There is customer reference number followed by customer name. The problem is customer
reference number may have alphabets, special characters and so on. But the characters will be in upper case letter only and it will not be more than two characters and never lowercase 
letters.

So, I'm trying to use regular expression to search a uppercase followed by two lowercase 
letters.

I succeeded in doing so, by using the expression

```
(.)[(A-Z)][(a-z)][(a-z)]
```

But I don't know how to give tab, as replacing it with `\t \1` deletes the first three 
character. Please help. and also please explain me, how it works.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Could you provide sample data and what you want it to become after the replace?

Comment: Try `(.[A-Z][a-z][a-z])`, then use your `\t \1` replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to separate the reference number from the name. If so, in Notepad++, go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   ^.+?\K(?=[A-Z][a-z])
   ```
2. Replace with:

   ```
   \t
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press "Replace All"

This will convert the following hypothetical example:

```
E34E!John Doe
123$#@ERFrank
```

To:

```
E34E!    John Doe
123$#@ER    Frank
```

You can test online at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xG6zH8), where you can find also an analytical explanation. To be honest though, my approach is a little bit complicated for a person who doesn't know a lot about regular expressions. You could use capture groups which will yield the exact same results and will be easier to understand, like this:

- Find: `^(.+?)([A-Z][a-z])`
- Replace: `$1\t$2`

Comment: Now i am understanding your expression a bit, I am justa newbie, and this expression worked perfectly well. Thank you very much and I appreciate it very much